# App rejection from google playstore saying *Your app is uploading users' Contact List information without a prominent disclosure*

Tags: google-play, google-play-services

Here are the permission my app uses as displayed on the playconsole:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO, android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO, android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED, android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT, android.permission.VIBRATE, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, com.esamudaay.customer.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION, com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID
```

It doesn't contain any contact list permission. But still i added a paragraph to privacy policy page.

**Import contact is an optional functionality strictly based on user experience point of view. we collect when you choose to import a contact from your device during placing certain type of orders. This imports a single contact from your device and we use this contact purely for app functionality standpoint. Please be aware that any contact submitted to our platform may be stored on our servers for future use. We don’t sell or share the contact name or phone number to third parties and only for internal purposes. By uploading a contact information to our platform, you acknowledge and consent to our collection and storage of your contact.**

But still it getting the same message from play console team.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of your packages is accessing this permission, hence the warning. You'll need to not only include a message in the Privacy Policy on Google Play but also display a message within the app. How you do this is up to you, but I would recommend following Google's best practices regarding this:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11150561?sjid=13218162944940030821-EU#zippy=%2Cuser-experience

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Build" - "Analyze apk" in the Android Studio and take a look at the AndroidManifest.xml of the generated apk.
Perhaps the line  can be found there.